# Error in enabling usb support in u-boot

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I have [Am-1808](http://www.logicpd.com/products/system-on-modules/zoom-am1808/), and i need to boot from usb instead of sd-card as explained [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Booting_Linux_kernel_using_U-Boot#USB_Storage). Previously i was using Davinci-PSP-SDK-03.21.00.4, but the uboot of this psp don't have usb support (i confirmed this by typing 'help' in  the uboot menu and it didn't have 'usb' command available). So i downloaded u-boot from denx tree which had 'usb 'command in the u-boot menu and then i added  the usb configurations in the da850evm.h as suggested by [Ti employee](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/60039.aspx). Here's the configuration:

```
/*
 * USB configuration
 */
#define CONFIG_USB_DA8XX        /* Platform hookup to MUSB controller */
#define CONFIG_MUSB_UDC

#ifdef CONFIG_USB_DA8XX

#ifdef CONFIG_MUSB_HCD          /* include support for usb host */
#define CONFIG_CMD_USB          /* include support for usb cmd */

#define CONFIG_USB_STORAGE      /* MSC class support */
#define CONFIG_CMD_STORAGE      /* inclue support for usb-storage cmd */
#define CONFIG_CMD_FAT          /* inclue support for FAT/storage */
#define CONFIG_DOS_PARTITION    /* inclue support for FAT/storage */

#ifdef CONFIG_USB_KEYBOARD      /* HID class support */
#define CONFIG_SYS_USB_EVENT_POLL
#define CONFIG_PREBOOT "usb start"
#endif /* CONFIG_USB_KEYBOARD */

#endif /* CONFIG_MUSB_HCD */

#ifdef CONFIG_MUSB_UDC
/* USB device configuration */
#define CONFIG_USB_DEVICE               1
#define CONFIG_USB_TTY                  1
#define CONFIG_SYS_CONSOLE_IS_IN_ENV    1
/* Change these to suit your needs */
#define CONFIG_USBD_VENDORID            0x0451
#define CONFIG_USBD_PRODUCTID           0x5678
#define CONFIG_USBD_MANUFACTURER        "Texas Instruments"
#define CONFIG_USBD_PRODUCT_NAME        "DA830EVM"
#endif /* CONFIG_MUSB_UDC */

#endif /* CONFIG_USB_DA8XX */
```

And on compiling i get these errors:

```
usbtty.c:126: error: 'EP0_MAX_PACKET_SIZE' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:219: error: 'UDC_INT_ENDPOINT' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:222: error: 'UDC_INT_PACKET_SIZE' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:245: error: 'UDC_OUT_ENDPOINT' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:249: error: 'UDC_BULK_PACKET_SIZE' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:256: error: 'UDC_IN_ENDPOINT' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:328: error: 'UDC_OUT_PACKET_SIZE' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c:338: error: 'UDC_IN_PACKET_SIZE' undeclared here (not in a function)
usbtty.c: In function 'usbtty_tstc':
usbtty.c:399: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_unset_nak'
usbtty.c: In function 'usbtty_getc':
usbtty.c:424: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_set_nak'
usbtty.c: In function 'drv_usbtty_init':
usbtty.c:553: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_init'
usbtty.c:560: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_startup_events'
usbtty.c:561: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_connect'
usbtty.c: In function 'usbtty_init_instances':
usbtty.c:683: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_setup_ep'
usbtty.c: In function 'write_buffer':
usbtty.c:846: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_endpoint_write'
usbtty.c: In function 'usbtty_poll':
usbtty.c:989: warning: implicit declaration of function 'udc_irq'
make[1]: *** [usbtty.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-    omapl1/drivers/serial'
make: *** [drivers/serial/libserial.a] Error 2
```

If u can please tell how can i get rid of these errors, [I have googled it  but didn't find anything useful] or if u can please give me a link of u-boot for Am-1808 which has 'usb' command supported in the u-boot menu.

**Update:**

I defined CONFIG_USB_TTY in the da850evm.h as auselen pointed, now i am able to resolve previous errors, but i am getting new errors, here's the output of the terminal:

```
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `write_buffer':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:846: undefined     reference to `udc_endpoint_write'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:890: undefined reference to `udc_endpoint_write'
 drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `usbtty_poll':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:989: undefined         reference to `udc_irq'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:999: undefined reference to `udc_irq'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:1009: undefined reference to `udc_irq'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `usbtty_init_endpoints':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:727: undefined reference to `udc_setup_ep'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:727: undefined reference to `udc_setup_ep'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:727: undefined reference to `udc_setup_ep'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `drv_usbtty_init':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:553: undefined reference to `udc_init'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `usbtty_init_instances':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:683: undefined     reference to `udc_setup_ep'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `drv_usbtty_init':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:560: undefined     reference to `udc_startup_events'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:561: undefined     reference to `udc_connect'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `usbtty_tstc':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:399: undefined     reference to `udc_unset_nak'
drivers/serial/libserial.a(usbtty.o): In function `usbtty_getc':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:419: undefined     reference to `udc_unset_nak'
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/drivers/serial/usbtty.c:424: undefined reference to `udc_set_nak'
lib_arm/libarm.a(bootm.o): In function `do_bootm_linux':
/home/user/Desktop/Uboot_Screwed/u-boot-omapl1/lib_arm/bootm.c:122: undefined reference     to `udc_disconnect'
```

Any idea how can i fix them ?

Thanks

Regards

usama

Comment: A config flag added to a header file probably won't inform the link stage to use the needed objects.  You need to figure out what drives the link - look at the makefile or configure script.  Also it may be worth doing the most thorough clean and rebuild, on the off chance that there is stale state in the tree which hasn't adapted to your configuration changes.

Comment: yes Charles u are right, i tried to change the MakeFile but it didn't help, anyway, thanks, i will try sth else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](http://gitorious.org/u-boot-omap3/mainline/blobs/f298e4b6dd56df3e35a13a6ddd572ca3baf06ad2/include/usb/musb_udc.h#line40) you need to define/enable `CONFIG_USB_TTY`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i solved the above errors by including enabling CONFIG_USB_TTY, but i have got few another errors, if u can plz help to fix them. Plz see the updated question. Thanks

Comment: @usamayaseen now you have a link problem which means udc stuff is not linked. I don't know that much about u-boot but you may be enabled CONFIG_USB_TTY in a wrong way. There must be a proper way for both compiling and linking.

Comment: yes u are write, actually the kernel source which i am using is missing musb_udc.h and seems broken. Thanks